# docker logs effected by -it parameter in docker run

Tags: docker

I have a strange behavior when searching with grep in docker logs which I don't understand.

As an example, I start a jupyter notebook container with following command.

```
docker run -it -d --rm --name test -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook
```

With that running Container I can now display the containers log and grep for a part of interest (eg. URL with token of the running jupyter server). This is done with the following Command and shows me the expected result.

```
docker logs test --tail 5 | grep -ozE "http://127.*"
```

But when the Container is started without the `-it` option this will not work and it just prints the whole log message.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The pipe between commands only pipes stdout. If the application inside the container outputs to stderr, this will be displayed bypassing the pipe and grep. You can adjust this by sending stderr to stdout before the pipe with a `2>&1`:

```
docker logs test --tail 5 2>&1 | grep -ozE "http://127.*"
```